# App that stores a collection of static HTML pages with webview and navigation

Tags: windows, android, cross-platform

Basically a web browser or an electron app but working like a catalog. Storing local HTML pages that I could put into the app, and listing them in a view that I can navigate easily.

What I'm planning to do with this app: a personal space to host simple webapps I wrote for myself like small CRUDs, data overview, calculators and what not; or webpages like reference sheets and articles.

I feel like something like this is already developed, but didn't find anything after some searching. Any help is appreciated :)